# How do I connect my laptop to wifi?

Tags: wireless

I downloaded Ubuntu on an old HP Pavilion dv6326us Entertainment Notebook PC. I am able to use an Ethernet cord to get Internet but I cannot connect to wifi whatsoever. Can someone please tell me how I can connect to the wifi? The wifi switch is on and everything.

Comment: what's specifically the problem? Can you see in the network menu the network you want to connect to?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all` Thanks

Comment: I cannot see any wireless networks that I want to connect to

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:1363]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
--
05:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection [8086:1092] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:30bb]
 Kernel driver in use: e100
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
everyone@OldComputer:~$

Comment: Please see: `hp-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes` Please find and move the wireless switch or key combination.

Comment: I moved the switch but I still cant find any wifi signals

Comment: Your driver requires firmware that is not installed by default. Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395

Comment: So I did everything that was said to do in that link. At the very end when I reboot, the computer starts to turn off but then freezes in the process. I then force shut it down and boot it up and I still have no wifi options. It's almost like nothing happened because the old bcmwl kernel I deleted is still in my additional drives.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can see the network menu and the network you want to connect to:

1. Click the network menu in the menu bar, and click the name of the network you want to connect to.If the name of the network isn't in the list, select More Networks to see if the network is further down the list.

[image: Network menu]

2. If the network is protected by a password (encryption key), enter
   the password when prompted and click Connect.

The network icon will change appearance as the computer attempts to connect to the network.

More info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html).

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot find any wireless networks whatsoever

Comment: As chili555 pointed out, see the [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)